# Moving footer notes (tags and date) to right side of a post as if in another column

Tags: html, css

I am playing around with my theme and it seems that the two main columns that I have use float to position, so I cant get around making a "new column" to put the notes on the right side of my posts.
Exactly what I need is to positing only the notes of every post on the top right side, inside the approximate space shown in the picture. 
I would really appreciate the help to learn whats going on.

REFERENCE IMAGE:

[image]

url of TUMBLR: http://est-fug.tumblr.com

and the HTML:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">

<html lang="en">
<head>

    <!--
        Reboot by justin.waggonerphoto.com

        Inspired by justplaintheme.tumblr.com.
    -->

    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>{Title}</title>
{block:Description}<meta name="description" content="{MetaDescription}" />

{/block:Description}
    <!-- custom  -->
    <meta name="text:Disqus shortname" content="" />

    <meta name="if:Show People I Follow" content="0">
    <meta name="if:Show Timestamp" content="1">
    <meta name="if:Show Date" content="1">
    <meta name="if:Show Search" content="1">

    <meta name="font:Body" content="Calibri">
    <meta name="color:Background" content="#FFFFFF"/>
    <meta name="color:Text" content="#111111"/>
    <meta name="color:Link Text Hover" content="#FFFFFF"/>
    <meta name="color:Link Background Hover" content="#111111"/>

    <meta name="if:Show post notes" content="1">
    <meta name="if:Endless scrolling" content="0">

    <!-- custom -->
    <style type="text/css">
        body {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 20px;
            background: #FFFFFF;
            font-family: Calibri, Helvetica, sans-serif;
            font-size: 15px;
            color: #000000;
        }
.navi {
                color: {color:Text};
                position: fixed;

            }

        a {
            color: #797979;
            text-decoration: none;
        }

            a:hover {
                color: #000000;
            }

            a img { border-width: 0px;

            }

        .clear {
            clear: both;
        }

        #container {
          width: 770px;
        }

        hr {
    height: 1px;
    border: 0;
    border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
    margin: .5em 0;
    padding: 0; 
}

        #left {
                        float: left;

                        Padding-left:25px;
            width: 200px;
        }

        #left a.h2 {
            text-transform: uppercase;
            font-size: 2em;
            line-height: 1em;
            color: {color:Text};
            text-decoration: none;
        }

            #left a.h2:hover {
                color: {color:Text};
                background: none;
                text-decoration: none;
            }

 }
            }

        #left .space {
            width: 100%;
            height: 20px;
        }

            #left .space.small {
                width: 100%;
                height: 10px;
            }


        #right {
            width: 500px;
            float: right;
        }

            #right .post {
                margin: 0 0 100px 0;
            }

            #right .post img {
              max-width: 500px;
            }

            #right .post h3 {
                font-weight: normal;
                font-size: 1.5em;
                margin: 0;
            }

            #right .post a.h3 {
                color: {color:Text};
                text-decoration: none;
                font-size: 1.5em;
                margin: 0;
            }

                #right .post a.h3:hover {
                    background: none;
                }

            #right .post a.h3.link {
                text-decoration: underline;
            }

                #right .post a.h3.link:hover {
                    color: {color:Link Text Hover};
                    background: {color:Link Background Hover};
                }

            #right .post blockquote {
                border-left: 2px solid {color:Text};
                padding: 0 0 0 15px;
                margin-left: 0px;
            }

            /* this is for chat */
            #right .post table {
                margin: 10px 0 0 0;
                border-collapse: collapse;
            }

                #right .post table tr {
                    margin: 1px 0;
                }

                #right .post table tr td {
                    padding: auto;
                    vertical-align: top;
                }

                #right .post table tr td.name {
                    text-align: right;
                    padding: 1px 15px;
                }

                #right .post table tr td.words {
                    width: 100%;
                    text-align: left;
                    padding: 1px;
                }
            /* that was for chat */
            #notecontainer{
                float:left;
            }

            ol.notes {
          margin: 0 0 50px 0px;
          padding: 0 0 0 0;
      }

          ol.notes img {
              display: none;
          }

        #right #footer {
            position: relative;
            right: 0px;
            text-align: right;
        }

            #right #footer .credit {
                color: #797979;
                margin: 50px 0 0 0;
            }

                #right #footer .credit a {color: #797979;}
                #right #footer .credit a:hover {color: {color:Text}; 

background: none; }

    a.install {
        width: 96px;
        height: 20px;
        background: url(http://static.tumblr.com/thpaaos/dHHkt0jor/install_theme.png);
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        top: 26px;
        right: 3px;
    }
    {CustomCSS}



    </style>

    {block:IfEndlessScrolling}
  {block:IndexPage}
  <script type="text/javascript" 

src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" 

src="http://static.tumblr.com/thpaaos/sZQkv2j7g/infinitescroll.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  var jQis = jQuery.noConflict();
  jQis(function($){
      // Infinite Scroll plugin
      // copyright: Paul Irish &amp; dirkhaim
      // license: cc-wrapped GPL : http://creativecommons.org/licenses/GPL/2.0/
      $('ul.allposts').infinitescroll({
          debug           : false,
          nextSelector    : "a.next",
          text            : "",
          donetext        : "{lang:No more posts}.",
          navSelector     : "div#footer",
          contentSelector : "div#right",
          itemSelector    : "div#right > .post"
      });
  });
  </script>
  {/block:IndexPage}
  {/block:IfEndlessScrolling}

    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="{Favicon}">
    <link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="RSS" href="{RSS}" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=820" />
</head>
<body>
<a href="http://www.tumblr.com/theme/15290" class="install"></a>
<div id="container">
<div class="navi">
  <div id="left">

    <a href="/" class="h2"><img src="https://38.media.tumblr.com/avatar_d3907ead3e72_128.png" width="100px" alt="Elisabeth Smith a.k.a. Estrella Fugaz"></a>
<br>

{block:Description}{Description}{/block:Description}
    {block:HasPages}
</br>
<hr>
        {block:Pages}<b></b> <a href="{URL}">{Label}</a><br/>{/block:Pages}

    {/block:HasPages}
<hr>

    {block:AskEnabled}<div class="space"></div><b></b> <a href="/ask">{AskLabel}</a><br/>{/block:AskEnabled}
    {block:SubmissionsEnabled}→ <a href="/submit">{SubmitLabel}</a>

{/block:SubmissionsEnabled}
  <hr style="padding-bottom:10px;">

  <a href="https://www.behance.net/elisabethsmith" imageanchor="1" style="margin-left: 0em; margin-right: 10px; margin-top: 20px;"><img border="0" src="http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-3C1MEDjJq1w/VdZdGgR6w_I/AAAAAAAAAuI/KE1tTxiA8gQ/s1600/behance.gif" /></a>
   <a href="https://www.flickr.com/photos/129111321@N05/" imageanchor="1" style="margin-left: 0em; margin-right: 10px; margin-top: 20px;"><img border="0" src="http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-pM3aiuiY1Xo/VdZdG7rVuHI/AAAAAAAAAuY/tuO1z3lZ-vQ/s1600/flickr.gif" /></a>
    <a href="https://www.facebook.com/e.fugaz.s" imageanchor="1" style="margin-left: 0em; margin-right: 10px; margin-top: 20px;"><img border="0" src="http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-0GZC94m-NWs/VdZfiGLZnGI/AAAAAAAAAu4/ZGONAw3VpqQ/s1600/fb.gif" /></a>


    {block:IfShowPeopleIFollow}
        {block:Following}
        <p style="text-transform:uppercase;">{lang:Following}:</p>
        {block:Followed}→<a href="{FollowedURL}">{FollowedTitle}</a><br />

{/block:Followed} 
        {/block:Following}
    {/block:IfShowPeopleIFollow}
    {block:IfShowSearch}
    <hr>

    <div class="space"></div>
    <form action="/search" method="get">
        <input type="text" class="search-query" name="q" value="{SearchQuery}" 

/> <input type="submit" class="search-button" value="{lang:Search}"/>
    </form>
    {/block:IfShowSearch}
  </div>
  </div>

  <div id="right">
    {block:Posts}
    <div class="post">
    {block:Text}
        {block:Title}<a href="{Permalink}" class="h3">{Title}</a>{/block:Title}
        {Body}
    {/block:Text}

    {block:Link}
        <a href="{URL}" class="h3 link">{Name}</a>
        <p>{block:Description}{Description}{/block:Description}</p>
    {block:Link}

    {block:Photo}
        {LinkOpenTag}<img src="{PhotoURL-500}" alt="{PhotoAlt}">{LinkCloseTag}
        <p>{block:Caption}{Caption}{/block:Caption}</p>
    {/block:Photo}

    {block:Quote}
        <h3>&#8220;{Quote}&#8221;</h3>
        <p>{block:Source}&mdash; {Source}{/block:Source}</p>
    {/block:Quote}

    {block:Chat}
        {block:Title}<a href="#" class="h3">{Title}</a>{/block:Title}
        <table>
            {block:Lines}
            <tr>
                {block:Label}<td class="name">{Label}</td>{block:Label}
                <td class="words">{Line}</td>
            </tr>
            {/block:Lines}
        </table>
    {/block:Chat}

    {block:Audio}
        {AudioPlayerBlack}
        {block:Caption}{Caption}{/block:Caption}
    {/block:Audio}

    {block:Video}
        {Video-500}
        {block:Caption}{Caption}{/block:Caption}
    {/block:Video}
        <p>&nbsp;<a href="{Permalink}"> <font color="#FF0000">☞</font> 

{block:Tags}
<a id="tags" href="{TagURL}">·{Tag}</a>
{/block:Tags}
        {block:Date}{block:IfShowTimestamp}

{12Hour}:{Minutes}&nbsp;{AmPm}&nbsp;&nbsp;{/block:IfShowTimestamp}<font color="#000000">|</font>{block:IfShowDate}

&nbsp;&nbsp;{Month}&nbsp;{DayOfMonth}&nbsp;{Year}{/block:IfShowDate}{block:Date}

{block:IfShowPostNotes}{block:NoteCount}&nbsp;&nbsp;<font color="#000000">|</font>&nbsp;&nbsp;{NoteCountWithLabel}

{/block:NoteCount}{/block:IfShowPostNotes}{block:Date}{block:IfDisqusShortname}

&nbsp;&nbsp;<font color="#000000">|</font>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="{Permalink}#disqus_thread" style="text-

transform:lowercase;">{lang:View comments}</a>{/block:IfDisqusShortname}</a>

{/block:Date}&nbsp;</p>

    </div>

    {block:IfDisqusShortname}
    {block:Permalink}
    <div class="notecontainer" style="padding: 0 0 50px 0;">
      <div id="disqus_thread"></div>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="http://disqus.com/forums/{text:Disqus 

Shortname}/embed.js"></script>
      <noscript><a href="http://{text:Disqus Shortname}.disqus.com/?url=ref">{lang:View 

the discussion thread}</a></noscript>
    </div>
    {/block:Permalink}
    {/block:IfDisqusShortname}

    {block:IfShowPostNotes}{PostNotes}{/block:IfShowPostNotes}
    {/block:Posts}
    <div id="footer">
        {block:Pagination}
            {block:PreviousPage}
                <a href="{PreviousPage}">{lang:Previous}</a>
            {/block:PreviousPage}

            {block:JumpPagination length="10"}
                {block:CurrentPage}
                    <span class="current_page">{PageNumber}</span>
                {/block:CurrentPage}

                {block:JumpPage}
                    <a class="jump_page" href="{URL}">{PageNumber}</a>
                {/block:JumpPage}
            {/block:JumpPagination}

            {block:NextPage}
                <a href="{NextPage}" class="next">{lang:Next}</a>
            {/block:NextPage}
        {/block:Pagination}
        {block:PermalinkPagination}
            {block:NextPost}
            <a href="{NextPost}">{lang:Back}</a>
            {/block:NextPost}
            &nbsp; | &nbsp;
            {block:PreviousPost} 
            <a href="{PreviousPost}">{lang:Next}</a>
            {/block:PreviousPost}
        {/block:PermalinkPagination}
        <div class="credit">
            <a href="http://justin.waggonerphoto.com">twentyten</a> by <a 

href="http://www.waggonerphoto.com">Justin Waggoner</a><br />
            </div>
    </div>
  </div>
<div class="clear"></div>
</div>
{block:IfDisqusShortname}
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
(function() {
  var links = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
  var query = '?';
  for(var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
    if(links[i].href.indexOf('#disqus_thread') >= 0) {
      query += 'url' + i + '=' + encodeURIComponent(links[i].href) + '&';
    }
  }
  document.write('<script charset="utf-8" type="text/javascript" 

src="http://disqus.com/forums/{text:Disqus Shortname}/get_num_replies.js' + query + 

'"></' + 'script>');
  })();
  //]]>
  </script>
{/block:IfDisqusShortname}
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.notes {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: -150px;
  width: 150px; // set the width as you need, I just put 150px as an example
}
```

And add "position: relative" to your '.post' class, so the .notes won't just float around the whole page.